# Sending LinkedList of Objects through ObjectInputStream throws exceptions 'NotSerializableException' and 'StreamCorruptedException'

Tags: java, sockets, exception, linked-list, network-programming

I'am writing a simple copy of 'Space Invaders'. I want to add network feature, and atm I have problem with Writing/Reading data.
So I have a LinkedList of (objects)Aliens and I want to send this to Client, to update thier positions.

The problem starts there:

On Server side I got exception:
 'java.io.NotSerializableException: sun.awt.image.ToolkitImage'

(Class Alien implements Serializable)

On Client Side:
 'StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: AC'

Code where sending data to client:

```
else if(Server) 
{
    while(true)
    {
        ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(1500);
        serverSocket = server.accept();
        new NetworkThreadHelp(serverSocket, board.GetAlienList()).start();
    } 
}
```

Code of NetworkThreadHelp:

```
public class NetworkThreadHelp extends Thread
{
    private Socket socket = null;
    private LinkedList<Alien> Aliens = new LinkedList<Alien>();

    public NetworkThreadHelp(Socket socket, LinkedList<Alien> A)
    {
        super("NetworkThreadHelp");
        this.socket = socket;
        this.Aliens = A;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            ObjectOutputStream objectOutput = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            objectOutput.writeObject(Aliens);
            objectOutput.flush();
            objectOutput.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Code where data is read:

```
else if(Client)
{
    Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1",1500);
    ObjectInputStream objectInput;
    while (true) 
    {
        objectInput= new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        Object object = objectInput.readObject();//Here code doesn't initialize, everything below this won't execute
        LinkedList<Alien> Aliens = (LinkedList<Alien>) object;
        board.UpdateAliens(Aliens);
    }
}
```

My question is: how to make this work, write and read properly?

Comment: The `NotSerializableException` is probably caused by serializing an inner class, which tries to take the containing class with it. The rest is a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely your `Alien` class contains an instance reference to an instance of the nonserializable `ToolkitImage` class.  You may need to refactor your code so the `Alien` class doesn't contain such an instance reference, for exaample by making that reference a static constant.  Alternatively, you can write custom `writeObject()`, `readObject()`, and `readObjectNoData()` methods for the `Alien` class as specified in the Javadoc for `Serializable`.

Your client side problem may or may not be a different problem, but I'd suggest fixing the server side problem first.  If you still have a client side problem, you can always post another question.